# How to make a style list out of database information

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, primary-key

I realize this isn't the typical question, and I will delete it tonight as to not take up space with a non-code error question, but I really need some help. I am trying to pull information from the question database and create a list of questions organized by the question title. When the user click on the question title, it brings them to the next page according to the question_id.

I posted the code for how the list of questions are currently being displayed, but I can't figure out how I would style them to make it actually look appealing. Would I use say 10 div tags with 10 different id's that all specify the background, and distance from the top? or would I use a table? or is there something else I could use?

I'm new with php and html, and I really don't know many ways to display information that is being pulled from the database....

Current_questions.php

```
<?php
        $i = 0;
        $str = "";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions";
        $result = mysql_query ($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 0)
            {
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) and $i<10 ) 
                    {
                        $i++;
                        $str .= $i . ". ";
                        $str .= "<a href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $row["question_id"] . "'>"
                                . $row["title"] . "</a> <br> ";
                    }
                print $str;

            }
```

?>

This code currently just prints a list of the title's, and that is not ideal. Thanks!

im not looking for how to code it, just suggestion on best way. Simple answer of a couple of words is all i am looking for –

Comment: Stack overflow is not your personal design team. It's here to help with code.

Comment: im not looking for how to code it, just suggestion on best way. Simple answer of a couple of words  was all i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

It really helps to learn some CSS

```
$toggle = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) and $i<10 ) 
                    {
                        $i++;
                        $str .= $i . ". ";
                        $toggle = !$toggle;
                        if($toggle)
                            $style = "background: Grey;";
                        else
                            $style = "background: White;";

                        $str .= "<a style='padding: 10px;$style' href='show_question2.php?question_id=" . $row["question_id"] . "'>"
                                . $row["title"] . "</a> <br> ";
                    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This is all I was looking for. Just an example of what you can do within php. It's hard to find examples online when you don't really know what to search for.

Comment: Or you could put the styles in a stylesheet rather than inline. CSS3 lets you use `nth-child` and not have to do any of that logic in the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the HTML entity which best describes what you are doing. To me that sounds like a [list](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/elements-list). Now decide if it is an ordered or unordered list. If unsure go with u-ordered

You'll probably want your html to end up something like:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href='show_question2.php?question_id=1'>Question 1 Title</a></li>
   <li><a href='show_question2.php?question_id=2'>Question 2 Title</a></li>
   <li><a href='show_question2.php?question_id=3'>Question 3 Title</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Now look around the internet for one of the many articles on styling a list.

Here are  3 to start you off:

1. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/ -- I'm a big fan of these guys
2. http://www.webreference.com/programming/css_style2/index.html
3. http://www.marcofolio.net/css/8_different_ways_to_beautifully_style_your_lists.html

[A real quick and dirty examples with lists](http://jsfiddle.net/9Eb7b/)

Comment: hey Jon, thanks for the examples, they are very helpful. I have messed around some with lists and tables before this, and I thought about using them to display the info from my database, but I wasn't sure how to integrate the php database info into it... everything I found on line suggested the format I used to pull info from the database, and I don't know how to set up tables within that.

Comment: @user1691618 your existing PHP would not require much modification at all to produce a list. I think you need to do a bit more reading to get an understanding of PHP and its' relationship to HTML. I'm not going to give you the code you need. You will learn more by working it out your self. I will give you some hints though... the `<ul>` and `<\ul>` tags can go outside the php block or at least  outside the loop. Now look at what you would replace with the `<li>` and `<\li>` tags